# database not storing accented characters properly

Tags: mysql, non-ascii-characters

pretty simple really, i've set all collations to utf8_general_ci, and yet, the database does not seem to be storing accented characters properly

for example, it is storing "Québec" as "QuÃ©bec"

now before the variable is inserted, it goes through the following function:

```
function dbprep ($v)
{
    $v = html_entity_decode($v, ENT_QUOTES);
    $v = htmlspecialchars_decode($v, ENT_QUOTES);
    $v = strip_tags($v);
    $v = trim($v);
    $v = mysql_real_escape_string($v);

    return $v;
}
```

also, i should mention that i use the following meta tag in my html:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
```

why is it not storing the values properly? it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8")` after `mysql_connect()` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing this query first:

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Comment: that didn't fix it and this is beyond frustrating.